# Add custom pre loader jquery.filer

Tags: jquery

How can I add custom pre loader showing % in `jquery.filer`?

Open a backdrop window while files uploading in onProgress method, now I need to show uploading percentage on section, screen shot below what exactly I need.

[image: Popup when choose the images]